# Overridding Equals and GetHash

Tags: c#

I have read that when you override Equals on an class/object you need to override GetHashCode.

```
 public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public Person(int personId, string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            PersonId = personId;
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName = lastName;

        }

        public bool Equals(Person obj)
        {
            Person p = obj as Person;

            if (ReferenceEquals(null, p)) 
                return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, p)) 
                return true;

            return Equals(p.FirstName, FirstName) && 
                   Equals(p.LastName, LastName);
        }


    }
```

Now given the following:

```
 public static Dictionary<Person, Person> ObjDic= new Dictionary<Person, Person>();
 public static Dictionary<int, Person> PKDic = new Dictionary<int, Person>();
```

Will not overridding the GetHashCode affect both of the Dictionary's above? What I am basically asking is how is GetHashCode generated? IF I still look for an object in PKDic will I be able to find it just based of the PK. If I wanted to override the GetHashCode how would one go about doing that?

Comment: see this link on SO..http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gethashcode

Comment: Why aren't you comparing `PersonId`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **always** override `GetHashCode`.

A `Dictionary<int, Person>` will function without `GetHashCode`, but as soon as you call LINQ methods like `Distinct` or `GroupBy`, it will stop working.

Note, by the way, that you haven't actually overridden `Equals` either.
The `IEquatable.Equals` method is not the same as the `virtual bool Equals(object obj)` inherited from `Object`.  Although the default `IEqualityComparer<T>` will use the `IEquatable<T>` interface if the class implements it, you should still override `Equals`, because other code might not.

In your case, you should override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) { return Equals(obj as Person); }
public override int GetHashCode() {
    return FirstName.GetHashCode() ^ LastName.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: -1 really doesn't anwser any of the questions that the OP is asking.

Comment: Removed the -1, especially for your spot about not having actually overridden .Equals!

Answer (score 4):

In your scenario, not overriding `GetHashCode` on your type will affect only the first dictionary, as the key is what's used for hashing, not the value.

When looking for the presence of a key, the `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` will use the hash code to find out if any keys *could* be equal. It's important to note that a hash is a value that can determine if two things *could be* equal or *very likely are* equal. A hash, strictly speaking cannot determine if two items *are* equal.

Two equal objects are *required* to return the same hash code. However, two non-equal objects are *not* required to return different hash codes. In other words, if the hash codes don't match, you're guaranteed that the objects are not equal. If the hash codes *do* match, then the objects *could* be equal.

Because of this, the `Dictionary` will only call `Equals` on two objects if their hash codes match.

As to "how to override `GetHashCode`", that's a complicated question. Clasically, a hashing algorithm should provide a balance between even distribution of the codes over the set of values with a low collision rate (a collision is when two non-equal objects produce the same code). This is a simple thing to describe and a very difficult thing to accomplish. It's easy to do one or the other, but hard to balance them.

From a practical perspective (meaning disregarding performance), you could just `XOR` all of the characters of the first and last names (or even use their respective hash codes, as Joel suggests) as your hash code. This will give a low degree of collision, but won't result in a terribly even distribution. Unless you're dealing with very large sets or very frequent lookups, it won't be an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your GetHashCode() and Equals() methods should look like this:

```
public int GetHashCode()
{
    return (FirstName.GetHashCode()+1) ^ (LastName.GetHashCode()+2);
}


public bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    Person p = obj as Person;

    if (p == null) 
        return false;

    return this.Firstname == p.FirstName && this.LastName == p.Lastname;
}
```

The rule is that GetHashCode() must use exactly the fields used in determining equality for the .Equals() method.

As for the dictionary part of your question, .GetHashCode() is used for determining the key in a dictionary.  However, this has a different impact for each of the dictionarys in your question.

The dictionary with the `int` key (presumably your person ID) will use the GetHashCode() for the integer, while the other dictionary (ObjDic) will use the GetHashCode() from your Person object.  Therefore PKDic will always differentiate between two people with different IDs, while ObjDic might treat two people with different IDs but the same first and last names as the same record.

Comment: -1 Your .Equals implementation is incorrect. The fact the two instances have the same hashcode is no guarantee they are the same. It is quite possible for the two strings XOR'd together to have the same hash code as two different strings XOR'd together. You should be individually checking the Firstname and Lastname fields.

Comment: Wrong. Hash codes can compare equal, even though the corresponding strings are different.

Comment: Fixed the .Equals() method.  And I do understand that hashes can collide, but I'm pretty sure I've read somewhere that the .Equals() results are supposed to match the GetHashCode() results regardless of that.  In the absence of an authoritative reference I'll bow to peer pressue here for the moment.

Comment: The problem here is that "Brandt Gideon" (my son) would have the same hashcode as "Gideon Brandt" (another real person so says Google). Not only would that break the `Equals` method, but it would also produce non-optimal distribution of outputs from `GetHashcode`. I should note that generally I am okay with using XOR as a hashcode generator, it just does not work well in this case since it could cause hash collision in the `Dictionary` collection.

Comment: @Brian - ah, you're right.  I forgot to add the position element to the individual hashes that make up the result.

Comment: @Joel: Well, yeah it would because XOR is associative. I just tried it and confirmed that FirstName ^ LastName = 68954133 with both test cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it. Since it is common for two different people to have exactly the same name it makes more sense to use a unique identifier (which you already have).

```
public class Person : IEquatable<Person>
{
  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return PersonId.GetHashCode();
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    var that = obj as Person;
    if (that != null)
    {
      return Equals(that);
    }
    return false;
  }

  public bool Equals(Person that)
  {
    return this.PersonId == that.PersonId;
  }
}
```

To answer your specific question: This only matters if you are using `Person` as a key in an `IDictionary` collection.  For example, `Dictionary<Person, string>` or `SortedDictionary<Person, Foo>`, but not `Dictionary<int, Person>`.