# How to implement a equality method?

Tags: c#

Given the examples below, how would I make `clientList` contain 5 clients in the second example?

I want the `list.Contains()` method only check the `FName` and `LName` strings and disregard the age when checking for equality.

```
struct client
{
    public string FName{get;set;}
    public string LName{get;set;}
    public int age{get;set;}
}
```

Example 1:

```
List<client> clientList = new List<client>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    client c = new client();
    c.FName = "John";
    c.LName = "Smith";
    c.age = 10;

    if (!clientList.Contains(c))
    {
        clientList.Add(c);
    }
}

//clientList.Count(); = 1
```

Example 2:

```
List<client> clientList = new List<client>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    client c = new client();
    c.FName = "John";
    c.LName = "Smith";
    c.age = i;

    if (!clientList.Contains(c))
    {
        clientList.Add(c);
    }
}

//clientList.Count(); = 5
```

Comment: You said you want to disregard age, but your 2 examples imply that age is indeed taken into account. Otherwise id expect both examples to result in 1 element in the list

Comment: @Jamiec Yes it is, but i want it to be not taken into account in the second example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Client : IEquatable<Client>
{
  public string PropertyToCompare;
  public bool Equals(Client other)
  {
    return other.PropertyToCompare == this.PropertyToCompare;
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, i can also implement the interface on a struct so even better :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a Class which implements IEqualityComparer , and pass the object in list.contains method

Comment: There is no List.Contains method version that could take IEqualityComparer - that method is part of LINQ to Objects and is an extension method declared on IEnumerable<T>

Comment: @Saurabh As MarcinJurazek mentioned, IEqualityComparer doesn't work with out LINQ

Answer (score 1):

Override [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) and [`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) in your structure:

```
struct client
{
    public string FName { get; set; }
    public string LName { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is client))
            return false;
        client c = (client)obj;

        return
            (string.Compare(FName, c.FName) == 0) &&
            (string.Compare(LName, c.LName) == 0);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (FName == null)
        {
            if (LName == null)
                return 0;
            else
                return LName.GetHashCode();
        }
        else if (LName == null)
            return FName.GetHashCode();
        else
            return FName.GetHashCode() ^ LName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

This implementation handles all the edge cases.

Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103308/overridding-equals-and-gethash) to know why you should also override [`GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using C# 3.0 or greater, try something like this:

(The following code is not tested, but should be about right)

```
List<client> clientList = new List<client>();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    client c = new client();
    c.FName = "John";
    c.FName = "Smith";
    c.age = i;

    var b = (from cl in clientList
             where cl.FName = c.FName &&
                   cl.LName = c.LName
             select cl).ToList().Count() <= 0;

    if (b)
    {
        clientList.Add(c);
    }
}
```